# YQL Query returning invalid XML

Tags: xml, wikipedia, yql

I'm currently using the following YQL statement to scrape page content of sites. Where `{EncodedURI}` is the page I am scraping. Ex: http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com

```
SELECT * FROM html WHERE url="{EncodedURI}"
```

For most URLs this works just fine. The XML is valid and  my application carries on. But on some URLs get invalid XML returned. Interestingly one URL I've discovered that causes this error is http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God.

I've taken the raw response from the query and put it through an XML validator and get the following error:

```
error on line 2 at column 6:XML declaration allowed only at the start of the document
```

It seems the XML near the end of the response is getting muddled but I haven't been able to locate the exact issue.

Any ideas?

**Update:**

I've changed the XML at the end of the response from:

```
</body></results></query>>!-- Stotal: 288-->
<!-- Lengine9.yql.ac4.yhouocolm-->
<
```

to

```
</body></results></query><!-- Stotal: 288-->
<!-- Lengine9.yql.ac4.yhouocolm-->
```

I can fairly easily have my application mend the XML so it works but obviously that solution isn't ideal. Does anybody know how to avoid this issue?

Comment: How are you executing your query?

Comment: In the [yql console](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/#h=SELECT%20*%20FROM%20html%20WHERE%20url%3D%22http%3A//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God%22%20) it works fine but if you copy the REST query at the bottom of the console you get the error.

Comment: I don't get any error when I do that.

Comment: That's odd. You pasted the REST query into your browser's address bar and didn't get back malformed XML? For reference I'm using Chrome I noticed that IE won't highlight that the XML is malformed.

Comment: Oh I see, delete the `&diagnostics=true` from the end of the query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see the error in firefox. I thing you could do to workaround this is ask for JSON response. Just add `&format=json` to the REST call. For example: [Try this](http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=SELECT%20%2a%20FROM%20html%20WHERE%20url=%22http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God%22%20&format=json). Atleast you would not have to worry about the feed not even parsing. Again this is not ideal but should work.

Comment: hmmm, I'll give that a try. My application is in JavaScript and I was using jQuery to search and collect the information from the response I wanted but I can change that. Just a little more effort!

Comment: works...I've also made a post on the YQL forums. Hopefully they log it as a bug. Thanks for the suggestion